# When new strings to be translated will be available on Launchpad for the next release?

Tags: release-management

Does anybody know when new strings to be translated will be available on Launchpad? If I try to open the translation page for this new version, I receive this notification:

> Translations for this release series are not available yet.

However in the past translations were available in advance.

Comment: 14.04 is currently in development.  Questions such as this one about the currently-in-development release are offtopic per the help center.

Comment: Translations started today ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu [release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule), hasn't reach the User Interface Freeze. It's counter productive allow people to translate stuff that latter on will get modified.

Remember that most of the strings are already translated from the previous release (less than two months ago, at December 9) so only the new strings that gets added (which can change) and the changed strings (from upstream) will get translated.

> The user interface must be stabilized at some point, so that documentation writers and translators can work on a fixed target that doesn't obsolete screenshots or documentation.
>
> After the user interface freeze (UIF), the following things must not change any more without approval of the release team and notification (usually via email, with a link to the mail in your exception bug) to the documentation and **translation** teams.

Comment: This is not true. Translating strings prior to string freeze is still productive, as unless all strings are changed on that day, there will be fewer things to translate at that point. However, as it is very early in the cycle, some packages are simply copied into the development archive from the last release, and so the translation strings in Launchpad will only show for the previous series, if a new version of the package hasn't been uploaded to the development series explicitly.

Comment: @dobey so, in what differ what you say of what I say? I'm saying that it's still early in the cycle for being the strings available to being translated, which seems that is what you comment anyways. I don't see where isn't there an agreement?

Comment: It's different because your claim is that the strings won't be there until the freeze.